# C++ basic stuff. What is missing??? Can't be that obvious

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

can anyone please help me understand why this program continues to give me errors? I am currently using Visual C++ 2008 Express and just error after error. I can't find anything obvious but please take a look.

```
# include "stdafx.h"
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    string name;
    int age, amountBeer, amountRootBeer;
    double beer, rootBeer, taxRate, sum, total, cashTendered, change, tax;

    name=“”;
    age=amountBeer=amountRootBeer=0;
    sum=total=cashTendered=change=tax=0.0;
    beer=5.99;
    rootBeer=3.99;
    taxRate=.07;



    cout << “Welcome to BeerMart; where all your beer needs are met. \n\n”
            << “Please enter your name: “;
        getline (cin, name);
    cout << “Hello << name << “.\n”
        << “Please enter your age: “;
        cin >> age;
    if (age > 21)
        {
        cout << “Enter the amount of beers to purchase: “;
        cin >> amountBeer;
        cout << “Enter the amount of root beers to purchase: “;
        cin >> amountRootBeer;

    else
        cout << “Enter the amount of root beers you want to purchase;
        cin >> amountRootBeer;
    }

    cout << “Please wait while we process your order.”;

    sum = (amountBeer * beer) + (amountRootBeer * rootBeer);
    tax = sum * taxRate;
    total = sum + tax;

    system (“pause.exe”);

    if (amountBeer > 0 && amountRootBeer > 0)
    {
    cout << “You ordered “ << amountBeer << “ beer(s) and “ << amountRootBeer<< “ rootBeers.\n\n”
        << “Beer cost $” << beer << “, and root beers cost $” << rootBeer << “.”        << “Your sum is: $“<< sum << “\n”
        << “Your tax is: $” << tax << “\n”
        << “And your total altogether is; $”<< total << endl;
    }
    if (amountBeer == 0 && amountRootBeer > 0)
    {
    cout << “You ordered “ << amountRootBeer<< “ rootBeer(s).\n\n”
        << “Your sum is: $“<< sum << “\n”
        << “Your tax is: $” << tax << “\n”
        << “And your total is; $”<< total << endl;
    }
    if (amountBeer > 0 && amountRootBeer == 0)
    {
    cout << “You ordered “ << amountBeer << “ beer(s)\n\n”
        << “Your sum is: $“<< sum << “\n”
        << “Your tax is: $” << tax << “\n”
        << “And your total is; $”<< total << endl;
    }

    cout << “Please enter the amount of cash tendered: $”;
    cin >> cashTendered;

    change = cashTendered - total;

    cout << “Your change is; $” << change<< “.\n\n”
        << “Have a great day!”;

    return 0;

}
```

Here is the errors...

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CH5HW Simple Beer sales, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>CH5HW Simple Beer sales.cpp
1>c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\ch5hw simple beer sales\ch5hw simple beer sales\ch5hw simple beer sales.cpp(16) : error C2065: 'ìî' : undeclared identifier
```

and the list goes on.

Comment: You didn't post any errors, which is a bad thing, but just look at the syntax highlighting in your post.

Comment: On which editor did you write this ? Or copied from some online document ?

Comment: "Code gives me errors" with no information about the errors is meaningless. The "errors" are right in front of you, and there is absolutely no reason you should not provide those to us. If the question is not important enough to you to put in the effort to write it and provide the details, it certainly shouldn't be important enough to us to try and figure out what the problem might be. Please [edit] and provide **actual information** about the errors if you want our help.

Comment: I wrote this myself. because I used textedit on my mac and then after installing VC++ on my mac bootcamp copied and pasted.

Comment: This issue has been resolved due to the wrong quotation marks. This occurred because I started writing my code in textedit app on my macbook pro and when copied the quotations were reversed. 

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
name=“”;
```

All your double quotes are not real double quotes, see the difference:

```
name="";
```

Comment: How do I change the double quotes?

Comment: @James: With the `backspace` and `"` keys on your keyboard.

Comment: @James Use a text editor to find and replace all the incorrect ones to `"`. If you mean how to input it, make sure you are using English input software.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As it turns out Copying and pasting from mac's textedit app makes the "" different than the real ones. I went into my VC++ and replaced all of them. Leaving me with 3 syntax errors that were incredibly easy to find and fix. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing closing quotes throughout your code as well.

```
cout << “Hello << name << “.\n”
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (age > 21)
        {
        cout << “Enter the amount of beers to purchase: “;
        cin >> amountBeer;
        cout << “Enter the amount of root beers to purchase: “;
        cin >> amountRootBeer;
        }   //<----you forgot this

    else
       {    //<--- and this
        cout << “Enter the amount of root beers you want to purchase;
        cin >> amountRootBeer;
    }
```